# Keep height of children div constant

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I wish to keep the height of the two children div's, `abc` and `def` constant, and each with height half that of their parent, `xyz`. I was able to do this using `flex` in CSS, but in each of the child div `abc` and `def`, I have tables in which rows are added dynamically. This causes the divs `abc` and `def` to expand to accommodate the rows.

I would like each of these to become scrollable when too many rows are added.

I have tried many solutions, but none of them seem to work.

Here is my code:

```css
#xyz {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
#abc {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}
#def {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="xyz" class="row">
  <div id="abc" class="col-border-bottom container-fluid">
    <h2>ABC details</h2>
    <table id="abc-table"></table>
  </div>
  <div id="def" class="container-fluid">
    <h2>DEF details</h2>
    <table id="def-table"></table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe using max-height?

Comment: Right, if I understood correctly you want to keep #abc and #def with a **constant** height, so you have to either define #xyz's height / max-height or #abc, #def height's / max-height's, otherwise it really doesn't make any sense, since you wouldn't be able to see any legible row in your tables, because #abc and #def would be too small!

Comment: What do you really want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, what I want is exactly as you describe. I defined the height based on viewport now. It works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a `flexbox` to get the overflow, you should wrap the flexbox child's contents into an `absolute`ly positioned contanier so that it can scroll on overflow.

So here is the summary of what I've changed in your code:

1. To demonstrate the overflow, set a specific height for `xyz` container. You can change this height as per your requirement.
2. Added `position: relative` and `overflow-y: auto` to the flexbox children- `abc` and `def`.
3. Wrapped the contents of `abc` and `def` into an absolutely positioned box:

   ```
   .flex-inner {
     position: absolute;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
   }
   ```
4. Added some borders and the tables in the boxes for illustration.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#xyz {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#abc {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#def {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.flex-inner {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="xyz" class="row">
  <div id="abc" class="col-border-bottom container-fluid">
    <div class="flex-inner">
      <h2>ABC details</h2>
      <table id="abc-table">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">Title</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>row</td>
          <td>row</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>row</td>
          <td>row</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>row</td>
          <td>row</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>row</td>
          <td>row</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="def" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="flex-inner">
      <h2>DEF details</h2>
      <table id="def-table">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">Title</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>row</td>
          <td>row</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>row</td>
          <td>row</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>row</td>
          <td>row</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>row</td>
          <td>row</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But in this case you're declaring a static height to #xyz, which can be undesirable, although not declaring one doesn't make any sense!

Comment: it can be dynamic if you want- even the height of the viewport... OP want the children to have half the height of the `xyz` :)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't explicit, is not about having a **static height**, **is about having a height defined** on #xyz! For example, OP could want to have the height of #xyz twice the size of the tallest child, and each one of the children have half the height of #xyz! Otherwise I don't see any reason for using display: flex!

Comment: Well, here I think a *static height* would suffice, don't you think?

Comment: Of course I agree with you, would make little sense not defining one!

Answer (score 1):

Give the child divs 'overflow:scroll', and 'height:[something]'.